# Expo useRouter hook navigating to a Blank screen

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-router

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import React from "react";

import Card from "./Card";
import { imageUrl } from "@/assets/Items";
import { useRouter } from "expo-router";

const Collections = () => {
  const router = useRouter();

  return (
    <View style={{ paddingHorizontal: 24 }}>
      <View style={[styles.header]}>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 20, fontWeight: "700" }}>New Collections</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity>
          <Text>See all</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", gap: 12, height: 200 }}>
        <Card
          onPress={() =>
            router.push({
              pathname: `/[id]`,
              params: { id: "item1" },
            })
          }
          imageUrl={imageUrl.item1}
        />
        <View style={{ flex: 1, gap: 12 }}>
          <Card
            onPress={() =>
              // [id] is in the app directory
              // this component was used in "(tabs)" which is also a stack screen in the app directory
              router.push({
                pathname: "/[id]",
                params: { id: "item2" },
              })
            }
            imageUrl={imageUrl.item2}
          />
          <Card
            onPress={() =>
              router.push({
                pathname: "/[id]",
                params: { id: "item3" },
              })
            }
            imageUrl={imageUrl.item3}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default Collections;
```

## I ran it on the web and it was navigating correctly but on mobile it is intermittent

- Sometimes shows a blank screen and sometimes navigates correctly what could be the issue
- I am not sure its issue with flex because I used flex: 1 style